# How to create this section style?

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I want to have a section style like in the below picture.

The size of corners should be flexible with the length of the section title.

[image]

Comment: what you try so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`tikz`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) to draw the corners and [`titlesec`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) to customize the format of headings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\sectionformat}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(title.base)]
        \node (title) {\thesection\hspace{1em}#1};
        \draw[double] (title.west) |- (title.south) (title.north) -| (title.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

% default values copied from titlesec documentation page 23
% parameters of \titleformat command are explained on page 4
\titleformat%
    {\section}% <command> is the sectioning command to be redefined, i. e., \part, \chapter, \section, \subsection, \subsubsection, \paragraph or \subparagraph.
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}% <format>
    {}% <label> the number
    {0em}% <sep> length. horizontal separation between label and title body
    {\sectionformat}% code preceding the title body  (title body is taken as argument)

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

**Edit:** Please note that long headings will *not* break automatically. If you add a `[align=left]` after the `\node` you can insert line breaks by hand with `\\`.